# Impossible to get a float array (invalid literal for float())

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to load tabular data textfile with numpy

```
import numpy as np

def test(nomFichier):
 phase=np.loadtxt(nomFichier,
   dtype={'names': ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'),
          'formats': (np.float, np.float, np.float, np.float, '|S15')},
   delimiter='\t', skiprows=0)
 return phase

test=calculF(PATH)
```

When I compile this code I get this error

```
invalid literal for float(): 0.00000000E+00     2.63580317992E+02     2.63487929269E+02     2.63534123066E+02     0.00000000000E+00
```

I don't understand because when I test if those numbers are recognized by python, it works well.

Comment: aren't those spaces instead of tabs?

Comment: Try opening the file and using readlines to print the first couple of them. I would guess that there is more characters than the '\t' being used as delimiters.

Comment: finally it works,i have changed the delimiter in the source file

Comment: what did you change it **to** please? feel free to write your own answer to the question if you think it might help future users.

Answer (score 1):

if you omit `delimiter` parameter, it will by default use any whitespace and you won't have to care whether the delimiters are tabs or spaces - http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html

Answer (score 1):

here is an example of the flat file

```
    1.74954955E+02     3.71345899229E-01     3.12953794281E-01    -1.25231427371E-02     0.00000000000E+00
    1.75135135E+02     3.73971853521E-01     3.13682391117E-01    -2.64543909236E-02     0.00000000000E+00
```

it is separate by a succession of whitespaces (5) and each row begin with  4 whitespaces

i have just removed the whitespaces at the beginning and transformed the other whitespace in tabulation like this:

```
with open(nomFichier) as f:
  f=(line.replace(' -','  -').replace('     ','\t').replace('    ','') for line in f)
  phase=np.loadtxt(f,delimiter='\t',
    dtype={'names': ('ang', 'p1', 'p2', 'p3', 'p4'),
               'formats': (np.float, np.float, np.float, np.float, '|S15')}, skiprows=0)
 return phase
```